# Azure API Policy Find And Replace - from "&lt;" to "<"

Tags: xml, azure-api-management

Within the Azure API Management, I have an API, within its outbound policy I wish to find-and-replace like this;

```
<find-and-replace from="&lt;" to="<" />
```

However, the "<" character is of course illegal since the policy itself is written in XML giving me the following error;

> Error parsing policy xml document. '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. Line 72, position 43.

**Reason:**

My backend API returns a text string which I want to "convert" into a valid XML.

**Questions**:

1. Would a string that uses & gt ; and & lt ;   (minus the spaces) instead of < and > still be XML valid?
2. If the answer to #1 is no, then, how can I find and replace within the Azure API policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're want to convert "<" (that is three separate characters) to "<" AND you're writing an XML you have to double encode things. Try:

```
<find-and-replace from="&amp;lt;" to="&lt;" />
```

This way XML after XML decoding first string will become "`&lt;`", and second - "`<`".

Note that this is not APIM problem, it's an XML encoding problem, for example this code:

```
new XElement("el", new XAttribute("at", "&lt;")).ToString()
```

produces such XML:

```
<el at="&amp;lt;" />
```